# Привязка элемента массива к методу класса

Tags: java, android

Как можно выполнить привязку метода класса, к элементу массива? (массив выполнен в виде ArrayAdapter), т.е. есть список на экране, как привязать к каждой кнопе (элементу массива) один из методов который я определил в классе.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы при клике на разные айтемы производились разные действия? Опишите свою задачу подробнее, в текущем виде очень трудно понять, что именно вам нужно. Не ваше понимание, как решить проблему, а саму проблему, которую вы не можете решить, потому что складывается впечатление, что вы делаете что то не так.